# Pass a pySpark script in Livy Session statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyspark, livy

I understand livy **session statement** intakes code statements like the below example.

```
data = {
 'code': textwrap.dedent("""
import random
NUM_SAMPLES = 100000
def sample(p):
  x, y = random.random(), random.random()
  return 1 if x*x + y*y < 1 else 0

count = sc.parallelize(xrange(0, NUM_SAMPLES)).map(sample).reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
print "Pi is roughly %f" % (4.0 * count / NUM_SAMPLES)
""")
}

r = requests.post(statements_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

but is there a way in which I can provide pyspark files, maybe something like this:

```
data = {
 'pySparkFile': file_name.py
}
```

I understand livy batch provides this functionality but I want an interactive session where users can pass multiple scripts one after another and we can also call variables of other scripts, just like in an interactive pySpark session.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this answers your question, but I managed to create a Spark session on EMR using cURL like this:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"kind":"pyspark", "conf": {"spark.yarn.dist.pyFiles": "s3://bucket-name/test.py"}}' http://ec2-3-87-28-125.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8998/sessions
{"id":0,"name":null,"appId":null,"owner":null,"proxyUser":null,"state":"starting","kind":"pyspark","appInfo":{"driverLogUrl":null,"sparkUiUrl":null},"log":["stdout: ","\nstderr: ","\nYARN Diagnostics: "]}
```

I inspected `/mnt/var/log/livy/livy-livy-server.out` and found this line which indicates that the session was successfully created:

```
20/08/31 18:02:25 INFO InteractiveSession: Interactive session 0 created [appid: application_1598896609416_0002, owner: null, proxyUser: None, state: idle, kind: pyspark, info: {driverLogUrl=http://ip-172-31-85-247.ec2.internal:8042/node/containerlogs/container_1598896609416_0002_01_000001/livy, sparkUiUrl=http://ip-172-31-95-182.ec2.internal:20888/proxy/application_1598896609416_0002/}]
```

Comment: I'm curious if this answers your question. Feel free to upvote or accept the answer if it helped